# Ability to not use ShadowDOM in Monaco Editor

Tags: shadow-dom, monaco-editor

I'm using Monaco Editor + a lot of custom CSS styles in my project. The problem is that "quick fix" feature (`languages.CodeActionProvider`) uses `ShadowDOM` for showing a quick fix suggestions:
[image]

Because of that, I cannot override any CSS-styles of this component due to `ShadowDOM` encapsulation feature.

Thus, the questions are:

1. Does Monaco Editor provide any API/workaround/etc. in order to not use `ShadowDOM`?
2. Mb it **is** possible to override CSS-styles of `ShadowDOM` element using **only** CSS ?

Thanks in advance!